# Is there a way to show that $\int x^ndx = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$ using induction?

Tags: calculus

Is there a way to show that $\int x^ndx = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$ using induction?

Here is what I have so far:

---

Base case: We want to show that $\int xdx = \frac{x^2}{2}+C$

Let $P(n)$ denote a partition of our (unspecified) domain of integration into $n$ intervals. Let $L(x,P(n))$ denote the lower summation and $U(x,P(n))$ the upper partition. Then we have that:

$$U(x,P(n)) = \Sigma_{i=1}^nx_{i}(x_i-x_{i-1}) > \Sigma_{i=1}^n\frac{(x_i+x_{i-1})(x_i-x_{i-1})}{2} > \Sigma_{i=1}^nx_{i-1}(x_i-x_{i-1})=L(x,P(n))$$

Note that we can telescope $\Sigma_{i=1}^n\frac{(x_i+x_{i-1})(x_i-x_{i-1})}{2}$ to see that it equals $\frac{x_n^2+x_0^2}{2}$

And uhh.. I feel like i'm close to finishing the base case but got stuck here. Can somebody help me out?

Comment: Why is your base case not: "By the definition of antiderivative, since $\displaystyle \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left( \frac{x^2}{2} \right) = x$, $\int x \,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{x^2}{2} + C$."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by induction. In *my* interpretation of induction. Assume that $\int x^{n}dx = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} $ (forget about the constant). Then we want to prove that $\int x^{n+1}dx = \frac{x^{n+2}}{n+2}$. Integrating by parts:
$$
\int x^{n+1} dx= \int x\cdot x^{n} dx = x\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+1}\int x^{n+1}dx $$
so
$$ \frac{n+2}{n+1}\int x^{n+1} dx  = =\frac{x^{n+2}}{n+1} \implies \int x^{n+1}dx = \frac{x^{n+2}}{n+2}$$

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use induction on $n,$ you need to use integration by parts.

Step 1: Show the base case yourself.

Step 2: Say it's true for some $n \in \mathbb{N}.$ Then we have  $\int x^ndx = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}.$ Forget $c$ now.

Step 3: Show the result is true for $n+1.$  By the integration by parts, $\int x^{n+1}ndx = x\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} - \int \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}dx.$ Then compute  $\int x^{n+1}ndx,$ and we're done.

The issue with this proof is that we've done it for any natural number $n.$ But in general it's true for other numbers which are NOT natural numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If $n=1$, then statement is correct.

Suppose that

$$\int x^k dx=\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}+C$$

Then,

$$\int x^{k+1} dx=\int x^k\times x dx$$

$$u=x, dv=x^k, v=\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}$$

$$\int x^{k+1} dx=\int x^k\times x dx=\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+1}\int x^{k+1}dx $$

Finally, we get

$$\int x^{k+1}dx=\frac{x^{k+2}}{k+2}+C$$

But, note that induction doesn't work for $\forall n\in\mathbb R\setminus \left\{-1\right\}.$